# How to perform an ordered probit regression using panel data in R

Tags: r, regression, mlogit

Please, can someone advise me on how to perform an ordered probit regression using panel data in R?. I received an error message when I tried the function 'plm'. The error message that I received was: Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, group.name, value = integer(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 9.

x <- data.frame("year" = c(2000,2001,2002,2000,2001,2002,2000,2001,2002),

"country" = c(1,2,3,2,1,3,2,3,1),

"infodemic" = c(1,3,2,4,2,1,3,2,2),

"democracy" = c(3,3,1,2,4,2,1,4,1))

I tried the following function:

model <- plm(Infodemic ~ democracy, data = x,
index = c("country","year", model = "oprobit"))

I would like to generate results with probability estimates?.

Comment: try `model <- MASS::polr(infodemic~democracy, data = x)`. Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89474/interpretation-of-ordinal-logistic-regression for interpretation

Comment: This is the error message I received: model <- MASS::polr(infodemic~democracy, data = x)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'infodemic' not found

Comment: maybe you have `Infodemic` I do not know what you have. That is an error that you can easily solve. Just debug the code. Also consider using factors for response

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.